# Node.js - Any way to Recover a Saved-Over Script that is Currently Running?

Tags: node.js, express, pm2, file-recovery

I've accidentally saved over an existing node.js script-file making it completely blank on the file system. I'm not using any type of version control, so this long script file seems unrecoverable.

However, the app is currently running via [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) (because it was started before I made this mistake).

Is there any way to recover this file from the running app via the node.js command prompt?

Comment: Nice question, from what I can see, if you have used `pm2 save` command to save the process, you can get it back with `pm2 resurrect`, I am still not sure if you'd be able get file syntax back.

Comment: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2